# How to Parent a Mesh Deform Modifier to an Armature

Tags: mesh, armature, parent

I'm using a Mesh Deform modifier to simulate belly wobble on a humanoid character. However, when I parent the deforming object to Big Boy's armature and bind, I get this crazy effect where the character moves and his gut stays pinned behind and stretches, like it's parented to itself or backwards or something.

From looking around online, it appears to be that this is caused by the Mesh Deform modifier "double dipping." It's parented to the armature, but at the same time, it's deforming the armature.

The only solution I've found is to make a clone armature that shadows my main character's animations, and parent the mesh deform object to *that* skeleton instead. It works perfectly, but it's clearly a hack. I was wondering, does anyone here know a more efficient way of parenting a Mesh Deform object to the armature it's deforming?

Comment: Your mesh deform is deforming your mesh, not your armature. I guess it's just a problem of weight painting, you need to unparent the belly from the armature so that the mesh deform cage is the only one to act on it, and parent the cage to the armature. But maybe share your file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: I'll need to redo the file to upload it... should be able to get to it tomorrow.

Comment: Okay, so I've been messing with this for a little while trying to recreate the error I was having yesterday... and it's not happening anymore. I think I just wasn't properly keyframing my animations (or not keyframing them at all) and it made me think my animations were somehow broken. Also, there's a brief lag in the mesh deform object snapping to the parent armature, which may have also been playing tricks on me. But it looks like the armature deform is working the way it's supposed to when parented. I genuinely do no know why I was having problems with it earlier.

Comment: actually I think mesh deform may not work because if you move the cage the mesh it is bound to won't follow, maybe it's better to use one of the 2 methods I explain here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/190827/best-way-to-achieve-floaty-bouncy-physics/190848#190848

Comment: It works pretty well. Wiggle bones are a good option for hair and some other things, but using the mesh deform gives met that gellatenous "Santa Claus" effect, with movement in multiple directions on lots of different vertices. It follows fine, and then I just save the effect as Shape Keys to animate later.